# OHLC Sampling is creating wrong timestamps candles

Tags: python, pandas

The data needed for sampling is coming from SQLite. It has been made available here: https://pastebin.com/LU7YApkX

**Code:**

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('sqlite_database.db')
query = "SELECT * FROM XXXX WHERE timestamp BETWEEN  '2019-01-24 09:15:00' AND '2019-01-24 09:59:59'"

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, index_col=[
    'timestamp'], parse_dates=['timestamp'])

candles = df['ltp'].resample('5min').ohlc().bfill()
print(candles)
```

OUTPUT **GOOD** `(Resample period = 3min)`:

```
$ python3 why_ohlc_failing.py
                       open    high     low   close
timestamp
2019-01-24 09:15:00  286.55  286.70  285.85  286.20
2019-01-24 09:18:00  286.10  286.30  285.50  285.90
2019-01-24 09:21:00  285.90  286.25  285.65  285.85
2019-01-24 09:24:00  285.80  286.90  285.75  286.65
2019-01-24 09:27:00  286.65  286.85  286.35  286.60
2019-01-24 09:30:00  286.70  286.70  286.20  286.25
2019-01-24 09:33:00  286.25  286.95  286.20  286.95
2019-01-24 09:36:00  287.00  287.50  286.95  287.40
2019-01-24 09:39:00  287.45  287.50  287.00  287.45
2019-01-24 09:42:00  287.35  287.50  287.00  287.50
2019-01-24 09:45:00  287.40  288.15  287.40  288.05
2019-01-24 09:48:00  288.40  288.45  288.30  288.35
2019-01-24 09:51:00  288.40  288.45  288.30  288.35
2019-01-24 09:54:00  288.40  288.45  288.30  288.35
2019-01-24 09:57:00  288.40  288.45  288.30  288.35
```

OUTPUT **GOOD** `(Resample period = 5min)`:

```
$ python3 why_ohlc_failing.py
                       open    high    low   close
timestamp
2019-01-24 09:15:00  286.55  286.70  285.5  285.65
2019-01-24 09:20:00  285.65  286.25  285.6  285.95
2019-01-24 09:25:00  285.95  286.90  285.9  286.60
2019-01-24 09:30:00  286.70  286.70  286.2  286.60
2019-01-24 09:35:00  286.70  287.50  286.6  287.15
2019-01-24 09:40:00  287.15  287.50  287.0  287.50
2019-01-24 09:45:00  287.40  288.15  287.4  288.05
2019-01-24 09:50:00  288.40  288.45  288.3  288.35
2019-01-24 09:55:00  288.40  288.45  288.3  288.35
```

OUTPUT **BAD** `(Resample period = 10min)`:

```
$ python3 why_ohlc_failing.py
                       open    high    low   close
timestamp
2019-01-24 09:10:00  286.55  286.70  285.5  285.65
2019-01-24 09:20:00  285.65  286.90  285.6  286.60
2019-01-24 09:30:00  286.70  287.50  286.2  287.15
2019-01-24 09:40:00  287.15  288.15  287.0  288.05
2019-01-24 09:50:00  288.40  288.45  288.3  288.35
```

OUTPUT **GOOD** `(Resample period = 15min)`:

```
$ python3 why_ohlc_failing.py
                       open    high    low   close
timestamp
2019-01-24 09:15:00  286.55  286.90  285.5  286.60
2019-01-24 09:30:00  286.70  287.50  286.2  287.50
2019-01-24 09:45:00  287.40  288.45  287.4  288.35
```

OUTPUT **BAD** `(Resample period = 20min)`:

```
$ python3 why_ohlc_failing.py
                       open    high    low   close
timestamp
2019-01-24 09:00:00  286.55  286.70  285.5  285.65
2019-01-24 09:20:00  285.65  287.50  285.6  287.15
2019-01-24 09:40:00  287.15  288.45  287.0  288.35
```

**ISSUE:**

If you look at all the **BAD** OUPUT  above for Sampling period of `10min` and `20min`, it starts from `2019-01-24 09:10:00` and `2019-01-24 09:00:00`.
This is wrong as I don't even have data anytime prior to `2019-01-24 09:15:01`. 
However, the same code works just fine for sampling period of `3min`, `5min` and `15min`.

Could you help me figure out what is wrong here. My understanding is irrespective of the sampling period, the resampled data should always start with `2019-01-24 09:15:00` otherwise it does not make any sense because there were no stock ticks available before that.

Answer (score 1):

Below works fine for all intervals:

```
data = df['ltp'].resample('5min', base=15).ohlc().bfill()
```

I had to add **`base=15`** although I am still trying to understand what's going on in here.

I further find that in oder to get teh desired result for various sampling periods, I need to add various `base` values as below:

```
resample('1min', base=15)
resample('2min', base=15)
resample('3min', base=15)
resample('4min', base=15)
resample('5min', base=15)
resample('6min', base=15)
resample('7min', base=16)
resample('8min', base=19)
resample('9min', base=15)
resample('10min', base=15)
resample('11min', base=16)
resample('12min', base=15)
resample('13min', base=22)
resample('14min', base=23)
resample('15min', base=15)
resample('16min', base=27)
resample('17min', base=28)
resample('18min', base=33)
resample('19min', base=42)
resample('20min', base=15)
```

whereas, for `1min`, `3min`, `5min` and `15min` does not need any `base` to work as below:

```
resample('1min')
resample('3min')
resample('5min')
resample('15min')
```

Still trying to understand the significance of `base`

Answer (score 1):

When you resample e.g. by `10min` it creates 10-min intervals, and `2019-01-24 09:10:00` corresponds to `2019-01-24 09:10:00 - 2019-01-24 09:19:59`:

```
df['ltp'].resample('10min').ohlc().bfill()
```

Output:

```
                       open    high    low   close
t                                                 
2019-01-24 09:10:00  286.55  286.70  285.5  285.65
2019-01-24 09:20:00  285.65  286.90  285.6  286.60
2019-01-24 09:30:00  286.70  287.50  286.2  287.15
2019-01-24 09:40:00  287.15  288.15  287.0  288.05
2019-01-24 09:50:00  288.40  288.45  288.3  288.35
```

Same as:

```
print(
    df.loc['2019-01-24 09:10:00':'2019-01-24 09:19:59', 'ltp'].iloc[0],
    df.loc['2019-01-24 09:10:00':'2019-01-24 09:19:59', 'ltp'].max(),
    df.loc['2019-01-24 09:10:00':'2019-01-24 09:19:59', 'ltp'].min(),
    df.loc['2019-01-24 09:10:00':'2019-01-24 09:19:59', 'ltp'].iloc[-1])
```

Output:

```
286.55 286.7 285.5 285.65
```

**Note:** If you want to start the resampled data at your first value:

```
tmin = df.index[0]
df.index = df.index - tmin
df = df.resample('10min').ohlc().bfill()
df.index = df.index + tmin
df
```

Output:

```
                        ltp                       
                       open    high    low   close
t                                                 
2019-01-24 09:15:01  286.55  286.70  285.5  285.95
2019-01-24 09:25:01  285.95  286.90  285.9  286.70
2019-01-24 09:35:01  286.65  287.50  286.6  287.50
2019-01-24 09:45:01  287.40  288.15  287.4  288.05
2019-01-24 09:55:01  288.40  288.45  288.3  288.35
```

Comment: +1 for your time. I kinda understand your logic. However, this way the timestamps works as expected but the OHLC values are not accurate.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer: Not sure if I understand your point on OHLC here. If we change time periods from 10, 20, ... to 15, 25, ..., we do expect OHLC values to change as well, right? For example, ‘open’ would now be taken as price not at the beginning of 10, 20, ... but at the beginning of 15, 25, ...

Comment: e.g. the actual OHLC candle @ `2019-01-24 09:25:01` for 10min interval is say `286.65  287.50  286.6  287.50`. However, when I follow the timestamp logic of yours, these values for `this` candle comes out to be `286.85  287.50  286.6  287.80`. So you see, these values are not correct. I am trying few things on top of your suggestion, Will provide it as answer if it works out.

Comment: OK, let's simplify this a bit and just compare `open`s. For 09:25:01 my value in the answer is `285.95` and it's the same as the price value at 09:25:01 in the original DataFrame (`df.loc['2019-01-24 09:25:01']`) as it should be. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, by the way, what you posted above as `286.65 287.50 286.6 287.50` saying that it's correct for `2019-01-24 09:25:01` is exactly my values at `2019-01-24 09:35:01`. Do you want to just shift the index by 1 position?